# Can I alter the default feed tracking text

Tags: opportunity, chatter-feed-tracking

We have a number of Opportunity fields setup in feed tracking and I was wondering if its possible to alter the default text that appears in the posts

e.g. John Doe changed Amount from $45,000 to $60,000 [custom text of field here].

Comment: I don't think you can do that. else I suggest if Amount is changed then you could write a logic in trigger to create feeditem for your record

Comment: I came to that conclusion just before and I discovered that we are only running Professional Edition and triggers aren't a feature .. :(